# Run A Function Every Time a Map Document is Opened

Tags: c#, arcobjects, opendocument

I am working with C# and ArcObjects. I have some functions that I need to run every time a map document is opened (.mxd, or any other type of map file as well). I have no idea of the code needed to accomplish this though.

An example would be that every time a map document is loaded up or opened, a message box could display that says: "Map document loaded successfully"

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders Sorry about that. Thanks for the edits.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an extension to do this, and add a handler for the [`ArcMap.Events.OpenDocument`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0049000000nq000000) event - there's a good example in the [API Docs](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001v000000vz000000) that has everything you need:

```
public class LogExtension : ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Extension
  {
    public LogExtension()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnStartup()
    {
      ArcMap.Events.OpenDocument += new ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IDocumentEvents_OpenDocumentEventHandler(Events_OpenDocument);
    }

    void Events_OpenDocument()
    {
      System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("I opened a document.");
    }
}
```